# adding kdevelop repository

Tags: kubuntu, repository, 15.04, kdevelop

I want to add the following ppa repository in kubuntu 15.04

[kdevelop package in Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdevelop)

However, I don't know how to add that via Muon package manager or Synaptic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow [this link](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdevelop/+index#) on [kdevelop package in Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdevelop) and use this repository:

[PPA for Andreas Roth](https://launchpad.net/~aroth/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

There, however, a large number of packages is provided. **Be careful what you install or are upgrading.**

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:aroth/ppa
```